# How to extract a list from the table

Tags: matrix

What's and elegant way to extract List with components  {x,y1} from the table with elements {x,{y1,y2,y3}?

Comment: If the second list is called `l` then `Take[l, 2]` or `l[[;;2]]`. There are many more possibilities. Perhaps you have considered these and found them inelegant, it would be good to know what qualities you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Please let me clarify the ambiguity in my question. The original list is, say. LL = {{0.1,{1,2,3}}, {0.2,{2,3,4}},{0.3,{5,6,7}};  The list that I want to extract is

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[x[n_]] := Subscript[x, n]
Format[y[m_, n_]] := Subscript[y, m, n]

(data = Transpose[{Array[x, 5], Array[y, {5, 3}]}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
(extract = {#[[1]], #[[2, 1]]} & /@ data) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Bob. This works, ad it's nice! Took a while to realize that  the lengthy first part is just to build an example, and the whole solution is in the "extract" line,

Answer (score 0):

```
SeedRandom[1];
t = Table[{RandomReal[1]}~Join~RandomReal[1, {1, 3}]
  , 5]
```

> {{0.817389, {0.11142, 0.789526, 0.187803}}, {0.241361, {0.0657388,
> 0.542247, 0.231155}}, {0.396006, {0.700474, 0.211826,
> 0.748657}}, {0.422851, {0.247495, 0.977172,
> 0.825163}}, {0.925275, {0.578056, 0.29287, 0.208051}}}

Some possibilities can be:

```
out1 = {First@#, First@Last@#} & /@ t
out2 = Transpose@{t[[All, 1]], t[[All, 2, 1]]}
out3 = t /. {x_, y_List} :> {x, First@y}
out4 = Cases[t, {x_, {y1_, y2_, y3_}} :> {x, y1}]
out5 = SequenceCases[t, {{x_, {y1_, y2_, y3_}}} :> {x, y1}]
out6 = Pick[t, 
   ConstantArray[{True, {True, False, False}}, Length@t]] // 
  Map[FlattenAt[-1]]
out7 = {Extract[t, {All, 1}], Extract[t, {All, 2, 1}]} // Transpose
out8 = t // Map[Flatten] // #[[All, 1 ;; 2]] &
out9 = MapAt[Nothing &, t, {All, 2, 2 ;;}] // Map[FlattenAt[-1]]
out10 = t // Map[Delete[#, {{2, 2}, {2, 3}}] &] // Map[FlattenAt[-1]]
```

> {{0.817389, 0.11142}, {0.241361, 0.0657388}, {0.396006,
> 0.700474}, {0.422851, 0.247495}, {0.925275, 0.578056}}

```
SameQ[out1, out2, out3, out4, out5, out6, out7, out8, out9, out10]
```

> True